# Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, koin

i have problem about unit test using mockito and koin dependency injection, i want to test viewmodel,i already inject and mock class service and respository, but when running testing error `there were zero interaction...`, that code like below:

```
class HomeViewModelTest: KoinTest {

    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Unconfined)

    val repository: NewsRepository by inject { parametersOf(scope) }

    val service by inject<Service>()

    @Mock
    lateinit var showLoading: Observer<Boolean>

    @Mock
    lateinit var newsList: Observer<List<Article>>

    @Mock
    lateinit var showError: Observer<String>

    @get:Rule
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    lateinit var server: MockWebServer


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        server = MockWebServer()
        server.start()
        BASE_TEST_URL = server.url("/").toString()

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        startKoin { modules(listOf(appTestModule)) }
        declareMock<NewsRepository>()
        declareMock<Service>()
    }

    @Test
    fun getNewsTest() = runBlocking {
        verify(service, times(1)).getSources(apiKey = API_KEY)
        val sources = arrayListOf<Source>()
        val dataResponse = SourceResponse(sources, "200")
        val response = Response.success(dataResponse)
        `when`(service.getSources()).thenReturn(response)

        val resultCallback = argumentCaptor<(List<Article>?, String?) -> Unit>()
        Mockito.verify(repository).getNewsList(id = eq("us"), response = resultCallback.capture())
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        stopKoin()
    }
}
```

and class repository like this:

```
class NewsRepository(private val scope: CoroutineScope) : KoinComponent {
    private val service by inject<Service>()

    fun getSource(response: (List<Source>?, String?) -> Unit) {
        request(
            scope,
            {service.getSources()}, { res ->
            when(res) {
                is Result.Success -> response(res.data.sources, null)
                is Result.Failure -> response(null, res.error)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

but this error display in verify class `HomeViewModelTest` and i tried to disable line `verify(service)`display error in `verify(repository)` and refer to line `request` in method `getSource` on `NewsRepository`, anybody help my problem, i'm beginner about unit test

Comment: What does your test actually do? I am not seeing a invocation of a method on your class under test.

Comment: i want to test service, using mockwebserver

Comment: I only see you starting the server. You need to interact with it during the test.

Comment: can you help me, with example maybe